# get attribution from data-descriptor class python

Tags: python, python-3.x

trying to learn how to use data-descriptor and see the information for document, https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html, my question under the class RevealAccess
what if I would like to return another attribution like name? Thinking about rewrite as a property for it, but since it have **set** once it set as str, class turn into string object, no other attribution can be access from **get**

```
class RevealAccess(object):
    def __init__(self, initval=None, name='var'):
        self.val = initval
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        print('Retrieving', self.name)
        return self.val

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        print('Updating', self.name)
        self.val = val

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = value
```